ESP32 Partition size and maximum program size #2
re. ESP32 Partition size and maximum program size
Further to the above issue:
The above is a neat little program.  However, is there any way I can reference/extract the "app0”  “partition->size” for use in an “#if” pre-processor expression?
Ideally I would want to use something like:
#if ((partition->size)<=1310720)
  #error “you must select a larger Partition-Scheme”
#endif

Or alternatively:
#if (PartitionScheme!=MinimalSpiffs)
   #error “you must select the Minimal SPIFFS Partition-Scheme”
#endif

// cf. esp32.menu. PartitionScheme.min_spiffs= Minimal SPIFFS (1.9MB APP with OTA/190KB SPIFFS)
(This is because I have a couple of projects which use 99% of the “Default 4MB with SPIFFS” program-storage-space, and will successfully compile and upload onto my ESP32 Dev Boards, but will cause the ESP32 to get stuck in a crashing boot-loop - I’m guessing the above mentioned “startup-reboot-forever loop”.  Thus for these projects I would like to add an above “#if” check to ensure I can force the compile to error/fail if the correct (larger) PartitionScheme is not selected.)

@Adriano & @6v6gt – many thanks for your below comments.

No, there is no way to find the partition size during compiling. As the code has nothing to do with the partition.

Some information from what’s been selected from the boards.txt options is available in Arduino for use in #if statements.
For example: “#ifdef ARDUINO_ NodeMCU_32S” can be used (which is taken from the “nodemcu-32s.build.board=NodeMCU_32S” option in boards.txt) to see if the “NodeMCU_32S” has been selected.  This is why I had hoped the selected “Partition Schemes” might also be similarly available for use in #if statements in some way!?

You can check the partition size once your code is running

That is what the example code in the original ESP32 Partition size and maximum program size post showed.  However in my above issue the code doesn’t run as I get stuck in the “startup-reboot-forever loop”.

..The file partitions.csv.. Arduino IDE 2.x …if you use a custom partition scheme, the IDE assumes that you are using a device with 16MB flash memory…

Thankyou – this is very useful info!

Update:  Interestingly https://github.com/HamzaHajeir/ESP32-Arduino-Builds/blob/master/tools/platformio-build-esp32.py has what appears to be a defined variable of form: "ARDUINO_PARTITION_%s" as shown below:
CPPDEFINES=[
        "HAVE_CONFIG_H",
        ("MBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE", '\\"mbedtls/esp_config.h\\"'),
        "UNITY_INCLUDE_CONFIG_H",
        "WITH_POSIX",
        "_GNU_SOURCE",
        ("IDF_VER", '\\"v4.4.5\\"'),
        "ESP_PLATFORM",
        "_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS",
        "ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32",
        "ESP32",
        ("F_CPU", "$BOARD_F_CPU"),
        ("ARDUINO", 10812),
        ("ARDUINO_VARIANT", '\\"%s\\"' % env.BoardConfig().get("build.variant").replace('"', "")),
        ("ARDUINO_BOARD", '\\"%s\\"' % env.BoardConfig().get("name").replace('"', "")),
        "ARDUINO_PARTITION_%s" % basename(env.BoardConfig().get(
            "build.partitions", "default.csv")).replace(".csv", "").replace("-", "_")
    ]

But this “platformio-build-esp32.py” file seems very different from the default https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/platformio-build.py version, and it is beyond my capabilities to incorporate this
 "ARDUINO_PARTITION_%s" % basename(env.BoardConfig().get(
  "build.partitions", "default.csv")).replace(".csv", "").replace("-", "_")

line into the default espressif file!

If anyone want's to know how to do this, an example (using board="ESP32 Dev Module") is:
// #if ARDUINO_PARTITION_default // from boards.txt: "esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.default=Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)"
//  #error "please change to a larger Partition Scheme"
#if ARDUINO_PARTITION_no_ota // from boards.txt: "esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota=No OTA (2MB APP/2MB SPIFFS)"
  Serial.println("ARDUINO_PARTITION_no_ota being used");
#else
  #error "wrong Partition Scheme has been selected"
#endif



With the ESP32 Arduino core 3.x it is relatively simple in that you include a custom partition file (partitions.csv) in the sketch folder. Of course you (probably still) have to remember to select "custom partition" in the tools menu. The file partitions.csv is even respected by the Arduino IDE 2.x for uploading sketch data, that is to the littleFS partition. However, currently, if you use a custom partition scheme, the IDE assumes that you are using a device with 16MB flash memory for the % usage statistics generated by the compilation process.

No, there is no way to find the partition size during compiling. As the code has nothing to do with the partition.
You can check the partition size once your code is running.
